# Getting a Request Timed Out from ACS Error when randomly performing Titanium.Network.HTTPClient Requests

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

**My Environment:**

Application type: mobile Connecting to ACS Titanium

SDK: 3.2.3.GA

Platform & version: iOS 7.1

Device: iOS iPhone Retina simulator, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5

Host Operating System: OSX 10.9.4

Titanium Studio: 3.2.3.201404181442

Node.ACS Engine: 0.8.26 or 0.10.22 (Tested on both)

**Question**

I have a mobile app that uses the Titanium.Network.HTTPClient to perform Web Service Requests to the Appcelerator Cloud. What happens is randomly I will receive the following error from Appcelerator

`{"type":"error","source":{"tlsVersion":1,"cache":false},"code":2,"error":"The request timed out","success":false}`

**NOTE:** The error message returned is dependent on which TLS Version I use for my HTTP Request.

If I rerun the same Web Service it then works. This is very random so it's difficult to identify what exactly the issue is. I have checked the following:

- I make sure not the set the "enableKeepAlive" property to True.
- I've tested with setting the "tlsVersion" to TLS_VERSION_1_0, TLS_VERSION_1_1, TLS_VERSION_1_2, which all produce the same result.
- I set the "timeout" property to 60 seconds to make sure it has enough time to run. Most of my Web Services only require about 5 seconds.

This issue only started around the 7th July 2014, where most of my web services were created a year ago already.